# .NET MVC3 Remove Currency Symbol and Commas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my model I have the following property:

```
 [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
 public decimal? Budget { get; set; }
```

When the user enters in $1,200.34, I need that value to be valid and strip out the currency symbol and comma.

In my controller I'm doing:

```
if (race.Budget != null)
{
   race.Budget.ToString().Replace("$", "").Replace(",", "");
}
```

The problem is that client validation doesn't pass the value for budget into the controller. I get a value of null. How can I override the client validation so that I can strip out the currency symbol and comma?

Thank you in advance for the help.

**UPDATE**

So here's the strange thing. Let's say I want to bypass client validation all together. I added `@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); }` to my view and it's still sending a null value for Budget when I submit to the controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a client side validation problem.  Your model has a field of type decimal?  The model binder will try to bind a value of $123,456.78 into that and fail, so the value will be null.  Here's one way to get around this:

Change your model to have a string property that masks your decimal:

```
public decimal? Budget { get; set; }
public string BudgetText {
    get {
        return Budget.HasValue ? Budget.ToString("$") : string.Empty;
    }
    set {
        // parse "value" and try to put it into Budget
    }
}
```

Then, just bind to BudgetText from your View.  Validate it as a string with a regular expression that accepts only money input.  It'll probably be the same regex you can use for your `BudgetText`'s `set` method

Comment: excluding the $, but with a comma in it, wouldn't this be a client side validation error if the proper cultures arent being considered, hence the jquery validation localization files?

Comment: Well, to test out what I'm saying, just take jQuery out of the picture.  Simply post a form like `<form><input name="Budget" type="text"/><input type="submit" value="go"/></form>` to your controller directly.  If you type in something like 1232.53 it'll work but $1,232.53 won't.

Comment: ya.. but you cant take it out of the picture completely as client validation is something to keep in mind here. I think as long as the currency symbol can be dropped.. all will be ok, otherwise the other options I posted can be used in addition with the currency symbol but to your point may have to be removed in binding.

Comment: I knew it had to be in the model binder. When I took away the client side validation I noticed it and your answer backed up my thinking. I actually found a decimal binder here that works: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx

Comment: actually see this for a slight change that may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111963/net-mvc-3-custom-decimal-model-binder

Answer (score 1):

So you can probably hook in some JQuery to pre-process the form field to strip the characters off you don't want (prior to form submission to the server).  This is probably the quickest, dirtiest approach.

For something reusable, have a look into [custom client validation](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/mvcConf/mvcConf-2011-Brad-Wilson-Advanced-MVC-3) [adapters](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2011/02/15/adding-client-validation-to-dataannotations-datatype-attribute.aspx).  The links aren't spot on, but should get you in the right direction.  For Brad's screencast, I believe the relevant parts are fairly early on.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the support for jQuery localization

[cliente validation using jQuery validate for currency fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143944/cliente-validation-using-jquery-validate-for-currency-fields)

also there is a plugin for currency validation as well

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/

check out this recent post as well for a $ in binding
[.NET MVC 3 Custom Decimal? Model Binder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111963/net-mvc-3-custom-decimal-model-binder)