# .NET MVC 3 Custom Decimal? Model Binder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In my model, I have the following decimal? property:

```
public decimal? Budget { get; set; }
```

I realize that I need a custom model binder for decimals which Haack provided at the following link: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx.

I have modified his code so that if the value being passed in does contain a currency symbol and/or comma then I strip it and then try to convert it to a decimal. This works but being that my property is a nullable decimal type, I also want it to accept nothing and move along its merry way inserting a null into that column in my database. Right now it inserts a 0.00. I know I'm missing something in my code but am having a brain freeze.

Here's the binder code:

```
 public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
    ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
    object actualValue = null;
    object newValue = null;
    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueResult.AttemptedValue))
        {
            newValue = valueResult.AttemptedValue.Replace("$", "").Replace(",", "");
        }

        actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(newValue, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
    catch (FormatException e)
    {
        modelState.Errors.Add(e);
    }

    bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
    return actualValue;
}
```

Again, the goal is to have decimal? act like it usually does but if there is a value which contains a currency symbol and/or comma and it can be converted to a decimal then to return that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the try block, I think you need something like

```
string valToCheck = valueResult.AttemptedValue;
if(valToCheck == string.Empty)
{
    actualValue = null;
}
else
{
    actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(valToCheck.Replace("$", string.Empty), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 }
```

In your code, you are always setting actualValue to the result of ToDecimal().

Answer (score 8):

You're probably better off to utilize the built in support for handling [NumberStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yd1h1be.aspx). By doing this you can account for more than just the common dollar sign but can also handle Pounds, Yen, etc...

```
public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
        .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
    ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
    object actualValue = null;
    try
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(valueResult.AttemptedValue))
            actualValue = Decimal.Parse(valueResult.AttemptedValue, NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
    catch (FormatException e)
    {
        modelState.Errors.Add(e);
    }

    bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
    return actualValue;
}
```