# jQuery validate plugin - currency

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am attempting to figure out how to validate a number in the jQuery validate plugin as legitimate US currency, max two decimal place zeroes, without commas or dollar signs (25000.00, 1.00 , etc)

I attempted this gist https://gist.github.com/jonkemp/9094324, but it seems to require the Dollar sign ($)

```
        jQuery.validator.addMethod("currency", function (value, element) {
      return this.optional(element)
        || /^\$(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*|(\d+))(\.\d{2})?$/.test(value);
    }, "Please specify a valid amount");
```

I also attempted this Stack Overflow [cliente validation using jQuery validate for currency fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143944/cliente-validation-using-jquery-validate-for-currency-fields)
but the validation code will not validate a number with two zeroes (1.00 for instance)

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("currency", function(value, element) {
    var isValidMoney = /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+)(?:,\d+)?$/.test(value);
            return this.optional(element) || isValidMoney;
        },
        "Must be monetary (0 or 0.00)"
    );
```

here is the jsfiddle that is showing these issues http://jsfiddle.net/d4ywy0fu/

any help is appreciated

Comment: haha getting some negatives here for no reason, would love to know why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am attempting to figure out how to validate a number in the jQuery validate plugin as legitimate US currency, max two decimal place zeroes, without commas or dollar signs (25000.00, 1.00 , etc)

Simply include [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js) and use the built-in `currency` method as follows...

```
currency: ["$", false] // dollar sign optional

currency: "$" // dollar sign required (default)
```

Note: commas are optional in all cases.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/d4ywy0fu/2/**

---

**NOTE**:  [Your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4ywy0fu/) also contains a [DOM ready handler](https://api.jquery.com/ready/#ready-handler) inside of another DOM ready handler.  While it's not harmful, it's totally superfluous.

```
$(function() {  // <- DOM Ready Handler

    $(document).ready(function() {  // <- DOM Ready Handler
        ....
```

Comment: yea i borrowed someone else jsfiddle and edited, didnt realize he had 2 dom handlers...perfect answer regarding the problem, thank you!